# Where to put the XSL: Choose Condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing

To insert a multiple conditional test against the XML file, add the `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`,
and `<xsl:otherwise>` elements to the XSL file

Ex:-

```
<xsl:when>
 <xsl:choose>
  <td> <xsl:value-of select="test"/></td> 
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
```

Is that Correct method?

Comment: What is your question? How the choose works? On the xsl:when there is a test="" attribute where you can specify an xpath etc.

Comment: multiple condition use multiple <xsl:when>

Comment: yes, where put <xsl:choose>?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It would be a good idea to show your input, your desired output, and the code you have written so far. An xsl:choose instruction in XSLT can go anywhere that any instruction is allowed, there are no special rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `<xsl:choose>` element is used in conjunction with `<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:otherwise>`
to express multiple conditional tests.

I found the Sample code:

```
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="price &gt; 10">
<td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="price &gt; 9">
<td bgcolor="#cccccc">
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</tr>
```